# git repository not loading in intellij

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have a GitHub repository and I have clone outside of IntelliJ.

I have imported the project using "import existing projects" option.
But IntelliJis not recognizing the git hence I am not able to view log or annotations.

If I try VCS->Enable version Integration, it is creating the new local repository.

Can you  help me out on setting up my IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

From the [import help documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html), you can try and import your project by cloning it (again) this time through IntelliJ IDEA (menu  VCS | Get from Version Control)

[image: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2020.2/get-from-vc-git.png]

That way, you will know if IntelliJ can clone your repository *and* detect a project.

Comment: that won't be possible. Because my project has to import as maven project

Comment: Try it out, for testing: see if you can select the type of project during the import.

Answer (score 0):

When you use VCS | "Get From Version control" you will have your project cloned with detected Git and Maven enabled.

If you do clone via command-line and then go to File | New | Project from Existing resources - please make sure that you choose the correct folder as a root of a project, it should contain .git folder.

Also it worth checking Preferences | Version Control and see whether there are some "Unregistered roots".